# Creating a loop to adjust dates/periods?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, merge

I have a big dataset of several thounds of persons. Each person has several treatment periods indicated by a separate row, where I have id, startdate, enddate and dose for each period. If 2 subsequent treatment periods are separated by more than 7 days, then they are separated by a third row indicating also startdate and enddate of the break and dose=0. However, if the break between 2 periods is less than 7 days, there is no such row.

Problem: What I want to do, is: for every person where there are 2 or more periods after each other with less than 7 days between, to merge them together to 1 continuous period. It is important that the peirods have same id AND same dose, as adjasent periods with different doses should not be merged togther altough the break between them is less than 7 days.

Here you see an example of my dataset:

```
library(data.table)

d=data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
             inn=as.Date(c("2017-09-11", "2017-12-21", "2018-03-19", "2018-06-27", "2019-01-15", "2019-04-29", "2019-11-20",
                           "2019-02-06","2019-04-07","2019-05-14","2019-07-13","2019-07-23","2019-09-25")), 
             out=as.Date(c("2017-12-21","2018-03-19", "2018-06-27", "2019-01-15", "2019-04-25", "2019-11-15", "2021-07-10",
                           "2019-04-07","2019-05-14","2019-07-13","2019-07-23","2019-09-21","2021-05-14")),
             dose=c("20","0","20","0", "20", "20","20","2.5","0","2.5","0","2.5","2.5"))

setDT(d)
```

The result I wish is:

```
e=data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
             inn=as.Date(c("2017-09-11", "2017-12-21", "2018-03-19", "2018-06-27", "2019-01-15",
                           "2019-02-06","2019-04-07","2019-05-14","2019-07-13","2019-07-23")), 
             out=as.Date(c("2017-12-21","2018-03-19", "2018-06-27", "2019-01-15","2021-07-10",
                           "2019-04-07","2019-05-14","2019-07-13","2019-07-23","2021-05-14")),
             dose=c("20","0","20","0", "20","2.5","0","2.5","0","2.5"))
```

I have tried to use "ifelse", but it gives error if there are more than 2 adjasent periods that should be merge together. I guess I need to create a kind of a "loop", but I cant figure it out..
I would appreciate any help..

Comment: Please edit your question and add a tag for the coding language

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the order of rows is relevant (and generally chronological), we can do this:

```r
d[, grp := rleid(dose), id
  ][, d := cumsum(c(TRUE, (inn[-1] - out[-.N]) >= 7)), by="grp"
  ][, .(inn = min(inn), out = max(out)), by = c("id", "dose", "grp", "d")
  ][, c("grp","d") := NULL]
#        id   dose        inn        out
#     <num> <char>     <Date>     <Date>
#  1:     1     20 2017-09-11 2017-12-21
#  2:     1      0 2017-12-21 2018-03-19
#  3:     1     20 2018-03-19 2018-06-27
#  4:     1      0 2018-06-27 2019-01-15
#  5:     1     20 2019-01-15 2021-07-10
#  6:     2    2.5 2019-02-06 2019-04-07
#  7:     2      0 2019-04-07 2019-05-14
#  8:     2    2.5 2019-05-14 2019-07-13
#  9:     2      0 2019-07-13 2019-07-23
# 10:     2    2.5 2019-07-23 2021-05-14
```